# More than a session from the same client to the same server, is it possible?

Tags: java, servlets

Using Java and HttpServletRequest,

I need that my java client against my java server uses more than one different session from different threads

Is it possible?

I mean

```
                    CLIENT
```

THREAD  THREAD  THREAD  THREAD  THREAD  THREAD

|              |              |              |                 |              |

SESSION SESSION SESSION SESSION SESSION SESSION

```
                    SERVER
```

Thast because I need to simulate many clients to my server to do a load test

Thanks

Comment: although i don't know your complete scenario in most cases i'd say "yes it is possible". e.g. if you access a WebApplication with two different browsers you usually end up with two different sessions

Comment: what is your client and server here..... are they servlets (or) jsp what...?

Comment: You can take a look at how JMeter works

Comment: Both are java apps, communicating with HTTP protocol... the server side is a Tomcat

Comment: When i execute the app throught JavaWebStart i can only take a session... if i do it as a desktop app i can take as sessions as threads i have

Comment: @DanielEgeaAlmagro Never put Solved in title, questions are already marked as answered which is better since we can search by, filter by, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is the pure java client... yes it is possible... you need to create multiple threads and make each thread to connect to server such that you can get different request and response objects for each thread..

the following kind of code should go into the run() method of your thread...

```
URL url = new URL("serer URL");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
.....
```

Comment: That is what I do now... and SessionID is allways the same

Comment: i assume it is not working because we are using URLConnection class which is TCP connection....try HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); conn.connect()... since it is http client in java.. it should go for a new session..

Comment: In some scenarios the way it take another connection is with URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(new Proxy(...blah..)). May it give my the same SessionID?

Comment: true... i accept...  because usage of Proxy will provide a new client IP for the server... then definitely it should create a new session at server

Comment: I just try with HttpURLConnection and get again the same ID

Comment: Definitely recommend using something like JMeter for the client - it will handle this type of issue for you. If you're keen to write the client yourself though, I'd use HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) which should also give a unique session id for individual connections

Comment: When i execute the app throught JavaWebStart i can only take a session... if i do it as a desktop app i can take as sessions as threads i have... That's all folks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by login in to multiple browser with same credentials each opened with "New Window". In m experience tools like load runner works this way.